# how to edit initrd.img to add a autostart application at boot in a live CentOS image

Tags: centos-6

I want to be able to open an application every time a live Centos image boot. I already have extracted the contents of initrd.img file, and analyse the init file, but with no success.

I know that i have to create a folder - autostart - in /home/centoslive/.config, and touch a file myApp.desktop That file should have as content: [Desktop Entry]

```
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/my/app
Hidden=false
X-Gnome-Autostart-enable=true
```

in resume the file should be in: /home/centoslive/.config/autostart/myApp.desktop

The problem is that i can't touch this file throw any of the contents of the initrd.img.

If someone could help me with that, i would THANK YOU ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add this application to the autostartup-items through the settings:

```
System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications
```

So you can add it without touching the `initrd.img`-file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Chris... Yes, i know that we can add apps to be opened at Boot throw that way, but as the CentOS is in RAM, everytime i start the OS that definitions are gone. Thats why tose settings haver to be in initrd.img